# PHP shellexec escape

Tags: php

I was wondering how can I escape the apostrophe ' and use variable from `shell_exec` in `php`. I am trying something like :

```
$output = shell_exec("su - $user -c 'ssh $hosts cat $fic'");    
$output = shell_exec("su - ".escapeshellarg($user)" -c 'ssh ".escapeshellarg($host)" cat ".escapeshellarg($file)"'");
```

Both commands doesn't work.

Thank you for your time.

Bob

Answer (score 2):

you have variable `$user` and `$host` before?

```
<?php                            
    $user = 'username';             
    $host = 'userForLogin@192.168.0.1';                    
    $output = shell_exec('su - '.$user.' -c \'ssh '.$host.'\'');
```

Answer (score 0):

You are assuming that `$user` exists in Shell. It doesn't. Try executing this:

```
$output = shell_exec("su - " . $user . " -c 'ssh " . $host . " cat $fic'");
```

Output command should be something like this

```
su - username -c 'ssh user@server cat $fic'
```

No need of escape chars.

Answer (score 0):

The following code does not work :

```
$user = 'Ucheck';
$host = '192.168.1.100';
$fic = '/tmp/zones';
$output = shell_exec("su - " . $user . " -c 'ssh " . $host . " cat " . $fic . "'");
```

The command  in shell works :

```
su - Ucheck -c 'ssh 192.168.1.100 cat /tmp/zones'
```